# How come python allows bash scripts to be run without being executable?

Tags: python, bash, pyqt4

I have a simple bash script that runs "apt update" I tried to call it via python like this. It runs although I didn't `chmod +x update.sh` it.

```
def updateUsingBash(self):
    p = QtCore.QProcess()
    p.finished.connect(self.onFinished)
    p.start('sh', ['update.sh'])
    p.waitForFinished(-1)

def onFinished(self, exit_code, exit_status):
    print "script finished with exit code :", exit_code
```

Comment: `sh update.sh` is telling `sh` to read `update.sh` as a data file containing text to run. That's true without Python involved anywhere at all.

Comment: That's the same as how `python foo.py` runs `foo.py` without it being executable either.

Comment: You're not executing `update.sh`. You're executing `sh`.

Comment: `sh` is not "using bash". `sh` is POSIX sh (on modern systems, 1970s-era Bourne on ancient ones). `bash` is bash. Even if `sh` is a symlink to `bash`, it'll run in POSIX compatibility mode when so invoked.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, thanks for explaining

Comment: ....which is to say: You should probably be using `p.start('bash', ['update.sh'])`, *especially* if your `update.sh` starts with `#!/bin/bash` (indicating that its author intended it to be run with bash) rather than `#!/bin/sh` (indicating that its author intended it to be run with any POSIX-compliant shell). Or just `p.start('./update.sh')`, after setting the execute bit, and thus letting the operating system ensure that the shebang line is honored.

Comment: I did just that after knowing the difference between the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did *not* execute `update.sh`. You executed `sh` passing it `update.sh` as an argument. That made `sh` interpret `update.sh` as a shell script.

By the way, note that `sh` is not exactly like `bash`.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly the same as how `python foo.py` runs `foo.py` without the latter being marked executable -- it's simply a data file containing script text, and the thing being *executed* is either `python` or `sh`, respectively.